# Read XML File with nested tables with VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm wondering how I can read an xml file which contains Stock Items and parse through it's nested tables to sum up a value for each stock item.

So for example my xml file is stored in C:\Temp\StockBalances.xml and contains the following:

```
<Message>
  <MessageName>string</MessageName>
  <MessageCreatedDate>2012-10-03</MessageCreatedDate>
  <StockCodes>
    <StockCode>
      <OwnerAccountCode>string</OwnerAccountCode>
      <StockCode>12345</StockCode>
      <Description>string</Description>
      <MoreItems>More Items here</MoreItems>
      <Balances>
        <Balance>
          <WarehouseName>Warehouse 1</WarehouseName>
          <Quantity>47</Quantity>
          <QuantityFree>-2848</QuantityFree>
        </Balance>
        <Balance>
          <WarehouseName>Warehouse 2</WarehouseName>
          <Quantity>3396</Quantity>
          <QuantityFree>748</QuantityFree>
          
        </Balance>
      </Balances>
    </StockCode>
    <StockCode>
      <OwnerAccountCode>string</OwnerAccountCode>
      <StockCode>12346</StockCode>
      <Description>string</Description>
      <MoreItems>More Items here</MoreItems>
    <Balances>
        <Balance>
          <WarehouseName>Warehoue 1</WarehouseName>
          <Quantity>1806</Quantity>
          <QuantityFree>4731</QuantityFree>
          
        </Balance>
        <Balance>
          <WarehouseName>Warehouse 3</WarehouseName>
          <Quantity>493</Quantity>
          <QuantityFree>1867</QuantityFree>
          
        </Balance>
        <Balance>
          <WarehouseName>Warehouse 22</WarehouseName>
          <Quantity>716</Quantity>
          <QuantityFree>-3575</QuantityFree>
          
        </Balance>
        <Balance>
          <WarehouseName>Warehouse 24</WarehouseName>
          <Quantity>-4478</Quantity>
          <QuantityFree>-4952</QuantityFree>
          
        </Balance>
      </Balances>
    </StockCode>
  </StockCodes>
</Message>
```

So for each StockCode in StockCodes I need to sum up the Quanity field in the Balances table.

I'd previously tried to this by reading the xml file in to a dataset which does work however there is no line between the stock item record and the balances table and the balance records can be dynamic. So for onestock code there could be three balance records and another there could be four records.

```
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(strExportFileName, New XmlReaderSettings())
Dim ds As New DataSet

' Read the file in to a dataset 
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)


' Close the file
xmlFile.Close()
```

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, this is not a programming service. That being said look at this answer in C# you should be able to easily translate to VB.net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935652/how-can-i-group-sum-values-in-linq-to-xml

Comment: I've updated the question. I'd tried this using a dataset but there is no link between the tables StockCodes and Balances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put results into a datatable using Xml Linq.  Not sure how you want the totals. You can sum the datatable values

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Data
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim stockcodes = doc.Descendants("StockCodes").First()

        Dim dt1 As New DataTable()
        dt1.Columns.Add("Owner", GetType(String))
        dt1.Columns.Add("Code", GetType(String))
        dt1.Columns.Add("Description", GetType(String))
        dt1.Columns.Add("Wharehouse", GetType(String))
        dt1.Columns.Add("Quantity", GetType(Integer))
        dt1.Columns.Add("Free", GetType(Integer))

        Dim dt2 As New DataTable()
        dt2.Columns.Add("Wharehouse", GetType(String))
        dt2.Columns.Add("Quantity", GetType(String))
        dt2.Columns.Add("Free", GetType(String))

        For Each stockcode In stockcodes.Elements("StockCode")
            For Each balance In stockcode.Descendants("Balance")
                Dim owner As String = CType(stockcode.Element("OwnerAccountCode"), String)
                Dim code As String = CType(stockcode.Element("StockCode"), String)
                Dim description As String = CType(stockcode.Element("Description"), String)
                Dim wharehouse As String = CType(balance.Element("WarehouseName"), String)
                Dim quantity As Integer = CType(balance.Element("Quantity"), Integer)
                Dim free As Integer = CType(balance.Element("QuantityFree"), Integer)

                dt1.Rows.Add(New Object() {owner, code, description, wharehouse, quantity, free})

            Next

 
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Mate, this is absolutely perfect. Thank you.

Comment: The two quantity variables should be integers instead of strings.

Comment: @user3608638 Did you forget to accept the answer?